# Better way to implement $.simpleWeather AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, plugins

## Background:

I'm using the simpleWeather.js jQuery plugin: http://simpleweatherjs.com alongside AngularJS + RequireJS.

In one of my service files, I have the following AJAX request and callback:

```
//AJAX Request
myAjaxCheck:function(city){

    $.simpleWeather({
        location: city,
        woeid: '',
        unit: 'c',
        success: function(weather) {
            var temperatureTemp = parseInt(weather.temp);
            colorSwatchService.weather = +weather.temp + '°' + weather.units.temp + ' ' + weather.currently;
            colorSwatchService.returnSeason(temperatureTemp); //Callback
        }
});

//Callback
returnSeason:function(temperature){
    var date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth();

    if (temperature >= 20){
            colorSwatchService.seasons = summerCollectionService;   
    }

    else if (temperature>4 && temperature <20 && (month>7 && month<12)){ 
            colorSwatchService.seasons = fallCollectionService;
    }

    else if (temperature>4 && temperature <20 && (month>1 && month>6)) {
            colorSwatchService.seasons = springCollectionService;
    }

    else if (temperature < 4){
            colorSwatchService.season = winterCollectionService;
    }
}
```

## Current Work-Around:

To update the view after the AJAX requests I'm using a $watch on the variables and I'm forcing a $digest cycle after the AJAX requests have been completed. This becomes messy and I don't think this is the right way to go about it.

## Question:

Is there a more elegant way to implement the $.simpleWeather AJAX request in my AngularJS code?
For instance, I know when grabbing data from a URL Angular has $http which will call the $digest cycle itself.

What is your opinion?

Comment: You can wrap their call inside angular version of $q promise and expose it by creating your angular services

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to all of this. Could you post the a code snippet of what you described?

I read the $q AngularJS documentation but I'm not certain I know what you're getting at.

Thanks!